# How do you set the default value of a combo box in the Winforms Designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm writing a Windows Forms app in C#, using Visual Studio 2010. It has a combo box.  I've set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`, and added a few lines to `Items`.

Question: Is there any way for me to set `SelectedItemIndex` in the "Properties" editor, so that line in the `Items` collection will appear as the default when the combo box appears?

I know I can programmatically set `myComboBox.SelectedItemIndex = NNN` in my `Form_Load` method, but I'm *sure* there's probably some way to do it in the MSVS IDE, too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what your asking for but if you want a specific item to be set as default I.E you load the form and there is already a value selected for you.

Simply put this into your `public Form1()` method.

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Test1"; 
//comboBox1 change to the name of 
//your combobox
//Test1 change to the item in your list of items that you want 
//defaulted.
```

I think that is by far the best way to do it.

Comment: Hi - Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately, that's the "programmatic workaround" I mentioned in my question.  I was looking for something you could configure in the IDE's property editor, at design time.  The Delphi IDE, allows you to edit the "ItemIndex" property to set ComboBox defaults.  I was hoping the MSVS IDE might have some equivalent design time functionality.

Comment: Thnx.  I've also asked on MSDN - I'll post back if I find a solution:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/a424deca-98f9-4b4d-8214-27421be1d6de  Otherwise, it looks like my answer is "No".  Thank you again - I appreciate it :)

Comment: So far, no response from MSDN :(  Besides manually setting "comboBox1.SelectedIndex = NNN" in my form_Load() method, I *also* had to manually set "comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;" to prevent the event from firing prematurely (before I finished all my "OnLoad" setup.

Comment: What an irritating problem - you can set the items in properties but not the index?!  Sure it's one line in the initialization but it still feels messy.  \*shakes fist at microsoft\*

Answer (score 1):

You could set the **Text** property of the *ComboBox* in the **Properties** window, to one of the values from your collection that you want as the default.

[image]

However this would require the **DropDownStyle** to be **DropDown**, and make your *ComboBox* editable.

If that's more acceptable to you, and you still want to make it un-editable, you can override the **KeyPress** event for the *ComboBox* as follows.

```
    private void comboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if the exact thing can be accomplished but Visual Studio provides a way of storing the values in its Application Settings, through which you can accomplish 2 things:

1. Set a Default value, the first time ever the Form is opened by the
   User (Note: Applicable only for the first time)
2. The last selection of the user gets saved and the next time the User
   opens the Form, his last selection gets reflected automatically
   which is a quite good User experience.

Select the ComboBox and open its Properties Section, Under (Application Settings), select the (Property Binding), once the Application Settings for ComboBox opens, select the Text property and create an Application Setting. This would be the value which is selected by default the first time the user opens the Form, after that whatever Selection is made by the User, would be reflected the next time the Form is opened.