# Setting the default index of my combo box only on initial open

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, combobox

In response to this question: [VS2010/C#: How do you set the default value of a ComboBox in the IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025136/vs2010-c-how-do-you-set-the-default-value-of-a-combobox-in-the-ide)

According to that user, in the Delphi IDE, one is able to, in the Properties window, set the ***DEFAULT INDEX*** of a `comboBox` when you open it ***INITIALLY***. However, no where can I find `Default Index` anywhere. When I mean initially, I mean not programmatically, and at the same time if and only if it's opened initially.

I've tried setting the index through `comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0`, but it turns out that I would be setting it every time I run the program, so that happens not only initially, but every time I run the program. Not what I want.

Does anyone know what I can do in the properties or argument events window on how I can do that..?

When I open my program initially, this is what it looks like:

[image]

My Properties tab:

[image]

EDIT: I could create a global integer counter which increments on each run, and have the default value set as 0 if and only if the integer is 0, meaning it's the first run, but if it's something I can do without doing it programmatically, that would be better.

Comment: How do you define the difference between "initially" and "every time I run the program"?  Even if you just set a property in the designer, that translates into a line of code which gets executed on the form initialization every time you run the program.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, when a user initially loads a screen with `ComboBox` ABC, you want to call `comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0`. The only way to do this is to track user data with either a file on the local machine or in a database.

Comment: I think I may have overcomplicated the explanation of what I want to achieve. I am simply interested in setting the default index, so when the user first opens my program, they see not a `blank` but the first index of my items collection.

Comment: If you want to display a value, not empty item on form load then use `comboBox1.SelectedText = "DisplayValue";`

Comment: You need to store the value somewhere so that once it's set, you can tell it has been and can restore that value when your app starts. You'll then be able to tell it's the initial (first ever) run because the stored value won't yet exist, and you can set the `SelectedIndex` to 0 or `SelectedText` to some default text.

Comment: Instead of text, could I have the defaulted selection be the first or second index?

Comment: What's wrong with using code to do this? Why does it have to be a component property?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage yes you can, Just set the index of the preferred item to be shown on initial load.

Comment: Should this be set inside the `Settings.cs` or inside `SettingsForms.cs`?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage do you want to set the default value when every time form loads or only first time ?

Comment: Could you show me both methods and I could choose from it? In my context it's a bit different, since I actually pull the form from a Grasshopper component, which is a graphical programming language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to set particular index of combobox as a default value set the index within form load,

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //To make combobox non editable
    comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

    //Set preferred index to show as default value
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

Comment: Can we set default index 0? actually i am facing same problem while my items count is 2 and i am setting index 0 i am getting index -1.

Comment: How did you resolve the issue of the combobox remaining focused after the form loads? Setting focus to another control and using SendKeys doesn't remove the focus, just wondered if you know how to resolve it. thanks.

Comment: @AshishJain  combo-box item index is zero based, it starts from 0.index zero is first item, -1 mean no item selected.

Answer (score 1):

In the design time, you can select using below way:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="OfferTypesComboBox" Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" **SelectedIndex="0"**>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="All" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="194"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="HSIA" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="194"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="IPTV" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="194"/>
    </ComboBox>
```