# Set index number in comboBox to display selected item

Tags: c#

I have several items in my ComboBox. But how to tell ComboBox to show only item number 1 from list as default? Currently at design time I have empty text.

Comment: You are gonna have to add some code dude..

Comment: Use tags! What is the question about? WPF? UWP? WinForms? WebForms? Xamarin? Something else?

Comment: something like this - Please see the link ?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312986/setting-the-default-index-of-my-combo-box-only-on-initial-open

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `SelectedIndex`:

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SelectedIndex as show value:

comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

NB: you should check the count of values in your Items array.

MS documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx